# Closing java swing window manually

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a small game in which one window opening the other when the game over.
I want to close only the game over window.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

But this closes the both windows. 
How to close only the second window?

Comment: Is it a JFrame or JDialog? something else?

Comment: People need to stop using `dispatchEvent`, it's a throw back to the AWT days.  `dispose` or `setVisible` is preferable as they provide additional event notifications to different listeners and perform additional tasks related to closing the window correctly

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. dispose method is what I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be closed from the game over window itself by

```
this.dispose();
```

or hidden by

```
this.setVisible(false);
```

You can also change the closing behavior with (assuming a JDialog where the default is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`)

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

If you need to close it from the parent `JFrame`, dont use `this`, but instead target the object

```
gameOverDialog.dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks.  this.dispose(); is what I needed.